# Replacement for `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType`

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType` is deprecated.  But what is it replaced by?  I'm migrating from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4.  I have the following code in a .hbm.xml file

```
    <property name="content" column="CONTENT" not-null="true" 
        type="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType"/>
```

Can I add an annotation to the Java file for this line?

```
private byte[] content;
```

If so, what annotation?

Comment: maybe [@Lob](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lob) is a way to go.